# What is the safe way to get the array class name at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Here is an example code that requires obtaining the class name of an array that is unknown at runtime:

```
//for calling methods declared similar to
//  void method(String... values);
//For primitive type we have other overloads and the following 
//is generic for classes 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> void invokeVaridic(Method m, Object host, T... values) 
    throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, 
    InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException{

    assert(values.length>0); //We assume all users passes at least one value
    Class<? extends T[]> c = (Class<? extends T[]>) 
            Class.forName("[L" + values[0].getClass().getName() + ";");
    m.invoke(host, Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length,c));
}
```

Since the type erasure nature the type of `values` is actually `Object[]`, I cannot pass this to `m.invoke` because it requires `String[]`. However since I am forcing the user pass at least one value I can use the type of `values[0]` to construct a new array.

I don't know what `T[].class` is.

I come up with the above code which depends on the interpretation of array's name in the byte code, but is it safe?  What is the suggested way to get `T[].class`?

Comment: getClass() on any object will return its runtime Class, and getClass().getName() will return the class name as a String.  Doing getClass().getName() followed by classForName() is just an inefficient way to to do getClass().

Comment: And doing `Class.forName("[L" + values[0].getClass().getName() + ";")` is an inefficient way to do values.getClass().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't necessarily be sure that the values in `values` will actually be of type `T`, because type-erased arrays are subject to heap pollution, and you should be prepared to deal with a `ClassCastException` at the point that you cast.  However, you can get the array type for a particular object by a slightly convoluted call to `Array.newInstance`:

```
Class<?> arrayClass = Array.newInstance(values[0].getClass(), 1).getClass();
```

Comment: @HotLicks `values[0].getClass()` gets the class of the element in position 0, not the array class itself.

Comment: OK, you got me.  It wasn't clear that the OP is attempting to narrow the class of the array.  But of course he must check all elements of the array to be sure.  The first element could be a String, the second element could be a Potato.

Comment: And if he wants the class of the array `values` itself then values.getClass() is it.  You can't get any more precise.

Comment: @HotLicks ...did you read the explanation of the question or my caveats in my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got hung up on "heap pollution".  What the heck does that mean?

Comment: @HotLicks That's when the first element is a `String` and the second element is a `Potato`.

Comment: But that's easily possible since both are Serializable, and T is "Serializable".  No "corruption" of the typing has occurred.

Answer (score 4):

`values` is of type `T[]`:

```
Class<? extends T[]> arrayType = (Class<? extends T[]>) values.getClass();
Class<? extends T> component = (Class<? extends T>) values.getClass().getComponent();
```

/edit

Complete example:

```
public class GenericArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo("", "");
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> void foo(T... args) {
        Class<? extends T[]> array = (Class<? extends T[]>) args.getClass();
        Class<? extends T> component = (Class<? extends T>) array.getComponentType();
        System.out.println(array);
        System.out.println(component);
    }
}
```

Prints the following with JDK 1.7.0_25

```
class [Ljava.lang.String;
class java.lang.String
```

Comment: At runtime, `values` will be of type `Object[]`, even if `T` was `String` at compile time.

Comment: I misspoke; most of the time, with correct code, `values` will in fact be of the correct type.  However, it is possible to pass in an array of bare `Object`; there [a specific compiler warning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html) about this case.

Comment: @chrylis Exactly, under normal circumstances the above code would work. The only reason it wouldn't work would be because someone introduced a bug into the code by mishandling a generic type.

Comment: Though it works but I am sorry I do not understand it from type-erasure point of view. I think at runtime vals will be `Object[]`. It is the type cast which is confusing me. Can you please explain

Comment: @Jatin I'm not sure how much explaining I can do. When you use a generic varargs parameter, a generic array is created. Why would you think it would be `Object[]`?

Comment: @Jeffrey Because this explains so: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html where it replaces `T` with `Object`

Comment: Although this code works it didn't solve my problem since I am still using JDK 1.6. But still thanks. BTW: in JDK 1.6 your `vals` is `Object[]` and you cannot use `@SafeVarargs`.

Comment: @EarthEngine That's strange. It works for me with JDK 1.6. And the `@SafeVarargs` is just a helpful annotation to prevent warnings in other locations of your code, it isn't strictly speaking necessary.

Comment: @Jatin The [erasure of a type variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) is its leftmost bound. Since we're invoking a generic method, the type argument will [be inferred](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) to be `String`, which changes the erasure of `T` from `Object` to `String`.

Comment: "`Class<T[]> arrayType = (Class<T[]>) values.getClass();`" This cast is not necessarily safe. The runtime class of `values` could be `U[]`, where `U` is a subtype of `T`. The most you can say is `Class<? extends T[]> arrayType = values.getClass();`

Comment: @newacct The cast won't throw an exception because of type erasure, but I see your point. I'll edit my answer accordingly.